# cookies in smarty tpl(probably syntax errors)

Tags: cookies, smarty

I got this code:

```
...

{assign var="name" value="some_value"}

{if $smarty.cookies.$name eq 'joc' }

    {assign var="test" value="`$product.total - 20`"}
    {assign var="test2" value="`$product.total_wt - 20`"}
    {assign var="var2" value="$smarty.cookies.$name"}

{else}

    {assign var="test" value="`$product.total`"}
    {assign var="test2" value="`$product.total_wt`"}
{/if}

...
```

Please help me to fix all errors and make this code to work. 
I'm newbie with smarty syntax.
 var2 is empty, the "if" condition always return false

Comment: What error messages are you seeing that you don't know how to fix?

Comment: So, that information needs to be in the question. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for some tips on writing a good question, and helping others to help you.

Comment: ok. Have you any idea why this code is not working?

Comment: I have some progress: the cookie is displayed, but it's value is displayed like "[value]"

Comment: Example: {assign var="nume_p" value="$_COOKIES[$productId]"}; {$nume_p|html_entity_decode:2:'UTF-8'|truncate:15:'...':true|escape:'html'} is displayed like [12345] instead of 12345

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<pre>{$smarty.cookies|@print_r}</pre>` to your template. This will help you debug why the if condition is not being met. You may not have set your cookie correctly in the first place.

Alternatively you could try http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/chapter.debugging.console.tpl to investigate the smarty variables state.